Is it possible to mask heatmap's (GradCAM) Region of Interest?
I am very new to using heatmaps (GradCAM). Can someone please tell me if it is possible to mask the Region of interest and save that image with masking. For example if I am trying to find an eye in a face image, the heatmap will have the eyes highlighted (Region of Interest). Now I want to get the original image with the eyes masked. Next time I give the same picture to the model, it will not find the eyes (since they are masked). Is this even possible?
I did not try it out as I don't have enough idea about this.
